# C++ Variadic Template Array / Accessing Elements

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, element, variadic-templates

In C++, how would I be able to access elements of a variadic template like an array? I have made a basic attempt to show what I am trying to acheive below, but, of course, it doesn't compile:

```
template<class... Args> struct Apple{
public:
    Apple(Args... A) : V(A){}
    Apple() : p(0){}
    void push_back(decltype(V[p]) v){
        V[p++] = v;
    }
private:
    Args... V;
    int p;
};

int main(){
    Apple<int, double> a(5, 6.5);
    Apple<int, double> b;
    b.push_back(5);
    b.push_back(6.5);
}
```

Comment: Easiest to use a `std::tuple`.

Comment: You need to have a look at variadic template. You are using it in the wrong way.

Comment: @chris - Thanks, but my task is to avoid a `std::tuple`

Comment: Note: you're not going to be able to determine which type to use at runtime. Selecting a type at runtime requires specific methods based on a dynamic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at variadic template. The `typename... Ts` is not an array. So you can't expect `Args... v` to be expanded as an array. Besides, how will you create an array with each element of different type?

Your requirement is quite similiar what the `std::tuple` provides, you should take a look at its implementation.

Take a look at [this GoingNative 2012 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Variadic-Templates-are-Funadic) given by Andrei. It's a great introduction to variadic template.

---

And here is one of my toy `tuple` when play with variadic template. There's some duplication with what C++11 stl provided, but its a toy any way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename... Ts> class MyTuple : public MyTuple<Ts...> {
  using base = MyTuple<Ts...>;

public:
  T elem;

  MyTuple(T v, Ts... vs) : base(vs...), elem(v) {}
};

template <typename T> class MyTuple<T> {
public:
  T elem;

  MyTuple(T v) : elem(v) {}
};

template <int i, typename T, typename... Ts> struct type_of {
  static_assert(i < sizeof...(Ts) + 1, "index out of range");
  typedef typename type_of<i - 1, Ts...>::type type;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts> struct type_of<0, T, Ts...> {
  typedef T type;
};

template <int i, typename T, typename... Ts>
typename enable_if<i == 0, typename type_of<i, T, Ts...>::type&>::type get(MyTuple<T, Ts...> &t) {
  static_assert(i >= 0, "index out of range");
  static_assert(i < sizeof...(Ts) + 1, "index out of range");

  return t.elem;
}

template <int i, typename T, typename... Ts>
typename enable_if<i != 0, typename type_of<i, T, Ts...>::type&>::type get(MyTuple<T, Ts...> &t) {
  static_assert(i >= 0, "index out of range");
  static_assert(i < sizeof...(Ts) + 1, "index out of range");

  MyTuple<Ts...>& base = t;
  return get<i - 1>(base);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  cout << typeid(type_of<0, int, char, long>::type).name() << endl;         // print i
  cout << typeid(type_of<1, int, char, long>::type).name() << endl;         // print c
  cout << typeid(type_of<2, int, char, long>::type).name() << endl;         // print l

  MyTuple<int, int> t(0, 1);

  cout << get<0>(t) << endl;
  cout << get<1>(t) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```